# How should I call a function from .so using python ctypes.CDLL?

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.x

I am trying to run a C++ code in my python project.
This is the *recompile.sh*, it builds the shared objects well.

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -I /home/pathto python/python3.8/ src/example.hpp \
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python38.so -o src/example.so
```

example.hpp:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int get_answer_c(){
  return 42;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example){
  boost::python::def("get_answer", get_answer_c);
}
```

When I try to import the module *example* I get this error:

```
AttributeError: ./src/example.so: undefined symbol: get_answer
```

Comment: how do you import it? Show code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

It compiles correctly only if I use `.cpp` instead of `.hpp`
(and `libboost_python38.so` is after `src/example.cpp`)

---

I compiled it correctly using this `makefile`.

First it compiles `example.o` and later `example.so`.

Item `-lboost_python38` have to be after `src/example.o`

---

I keep code in `.cpp` because `.hpp` seems for headers.

---

`makefile`

```
src/example.so: src/example.o
    g++ \
    -shared \
    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    -o src/example.so \
    src/example.o \
    -lboost_python38

src/example.o:
    g++ \
    -c \
    -fPIC \
    -I/usr/include/python3.8 \
    -o src/example.o \
    src/example.cpp

clean:
    rm src/example.o src/example.so
```

---

**EDIT:**

I get correct module even with

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -I/usr/include/python3.8 -o src/example.so src/example.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python38.so
```

or with different order

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -I/usr/include/python3.8 src/example.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python38.so -o src/example.so
```

---

I alwasy go to folder `src`, run `python3.8` and run lines

```
import example

example.get_answer()
```